# Hot to get and set cookie in an API call from Blackberry app?

Tags: blackberry, cookies

Can anybody please, help me out in get/set cookie in http get request from a blackberry application ?

I was able to get the cookie by iterating through the response header. I don't know whether this is the best practice to retrieve the cookie. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating through the headers is pretty much all you can do to read cookies from an Http response.

To set the cookie, you have to use the "Set-Cookie" header and have name=value defined for the Http requests. If you don't know how to set headers for HttpRequests in Blackberry, you have to use the `setRequestProperty` method for an `HttpConnection` object.

Here, the method call would be something like this:

`con.setRequestProperty ("Set-Cookie", "NAME=VALUE");`

Comment: I was using the setRequestPropertyMethod; but the cookie value was getting corrupted and that's why I didn't get it right.

Anyways, answer is correct and it made us check it again. Thanks..!!